# tinymce how to specify the css file to be used for tinymce in another js file

Tags: css, tinymce

I have made my own plugin.I am using tinymce with it.Now, to specify the css file for tinymce we use content_css inside tinymce.init, but in my case i dont want to specify the css file path in tinymce file itself but want it to be looked up in my plugin.js file. How can i do that?

Comment: what are you trying  to say?

Comment: Done.Thought of sharing the solution here. In my plugin's js file which i ahve called plugin.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.Thought of sharing the solution here. In my plugin's js file which i have called plugin.js i have written

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('matheditor', function(editor, url) {
    function TinyMCEAdapter(){
    var pluginPath = '../editor.html',
        editOptions = null,
        editedElementId = null;
    editor.settings.content_css = '../themes/tangerine/css/equationeditor.css';
    }}
```

here the parameter matheditor is the name  of my plugin.We set the content_css for tinymce with the line

```
editor.settings.content_css = '../themes/tangerine/css/equationeditor.css';`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

You call loadjscssfile function as soon as your plugin is loaded.